# jquery mouseenter add class not working

Tags: jquery, wordpress

Trying to make this script work on WordPress and is not working. No errors are showing on the chrome dev console, what could be the issue?

Here is the html:

```
<script type='text/javascript' src='https://gravitywiz.com/wp-includes/js/jquery/jquery.js?ver=1.12.4'></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $('.bm-header__nav-menu-item.has-submenu').on({
        mouseenter: function() {
            var submenu = $(this).find('.bm-header__nav-submenu');
            submenu.show(0).removeClass('nav-submenu-hide').addClass('nav-submenu-show');
        },
        mouseleave: function() {
            var submenu = $(this).find('.bm-header__nav-submenu');
            submenu.removeClass('nav-submenu-show').addClass('nav-submenu-hide').delay(300).hide(0);
        }
    });

   $('.nav-submenu-langs .bm-header__nav-submenu-item').on('click', function(){
        $('.nav-submenu-langs .bm-header__nav-submenu-item').removeClass('lang-item-active');
       $(this).addClass('lang-item-active');
    });
});
</script>

    <header class="bm-header transparent_nav">
        <div class="bm-header__wrp inner960 cf">

            <div class="bm-header__logo">
                <a href="#" class="bm-header__logo-img"></a>
            </div>

            <nav class="bm-header__nav">
                <ul class="bm-header__nav-menu">
                                                                                                                                                                                <li class="bm-header__nav-menu-item has-submenu ">
                                                                            <a href="#" class="bm-header__nav-menu-item-l ">#</a>
                                                                                                                <ul class="bm-header__nav-submenu nav-submenu-products ">
                                                                                                                                                <li class="bm-header__nav-submenu-item">
                                                                                                            <a href="#" class="bm-header__nav-submenu-item-l product-item-brick"><span>#</span><br/># </a>
                                                                                                        </li>
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            <li class="bm-header__nav-submenu-item">
                                                                                                            <a href="#" class="bm-header__nav-submenu-item-l product-item-pwlocal"><span>#</span><br/> #</a>
                                                                                                        </li>
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            <li class="bm-header__nav-submenu-item">
                                                                                                            <a href="#" class="bm-header__nav-submenu-item-l product-item-spiderpipe"><span>#</a>
                                                                                                        </li>
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            </ul>
                                                                        </li>
                                                                                                                                                                                                                    <li class="bm-header__nav-menu-item ">
                                                                            <a href="#" class="bm-header__nav-menu-item-l ">#</a>
                                                                                                            </li>
                                                                                                                                                                                                                    <li class="bm-header__nav-menu-item ">
                                                                            <a href="#" class="bm-header__nav-menu-item-l ">#</a>
                                                                                                            </li>
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        <li class="bm-header__nav-menu-item ">
                                                                            <a href="#" class="bm-header__nav-menu-item-l ">#</a>
                                                                                                            </li>
                                <li class="bm-header__nav-menu-item has-submenu ">
                                                                            <a href="#" class="bm-header__nav-menu-item-l ">#</a>
                                                                                                                <ul class="bm-header__nav-submenu ">
                                                                                                                                                <li class="bm-header__nav-submenu-item">
                                                                                                            <a href="#" class="bm-header__nav-submenu-item-l">#</a>
                                                                                                        </li>
                                                                                                                                                                                                <li class="bm-header__nav-submenu-item">
                                                                                                            <a href="#" class="bm-header__nav-submenu-item-l">#</a>
                                                                                                        </li>
                                                                                                                                                                                                <li class="bm-header__nav-submenu-item">
                                                                                                            <a href="#" class="bm-header__nav-submenu-item-l">#</a>
                                                                                                        </li>
                                                                                                                                                                                                <li class="bm-header__nav-submenu-item">
                                                                                                            <a href="#" class="bm-header__nav-submenu-item-l">#</a>
                                                                                                        </li>
                                                                                                                                                                                                <li class="bm-header__nav-submenu-item">
                                                                                                            <a href="#" class="bm-header__nav-submenu-item-l">#</a>
                                                                                                        </li>
                                                                                                                                                                                                <li class="bm-header__nav-submenu-item">
                                                                                                            <a href="#" target="_blank" class="bm-header__nav-submenu-item-l">#</a>
                                                                                                        </li>
                                                                                                                                    </ul>
                                                                        </li>

                    <div class="bm-header__nav-account-area">
                                                    <li class="bm-header__nav-menu-item menu-item-demo"><a href="#" class="bm-header__nav-menu-item-l">#</a></li>
                            <li class="bm-header__nav-menu-item menu-item-memb"><a href="#" class="bm-header__nav-menu-item-l">#</a></li>

                        <li class="bm-header__nav-menu-item has-submenu menu-item-lang-switcher">
                            <div class="menu-item-current-lang lang-item-us">US</div>
                            <ul class="bm-header__nav-submenu nav-submenu-langs">
                                                                                                        <li class="bm-header__nav-submenu-item lang-item-us "><a href="#" class="bm-header__nav-submenu-item-l">English</a></li>

                                                                                                </ul>
                        </li>
                    </div>
                </ul>
            </nav>
        </div>
</header>
```

I am also using a similar script with the same menu which is working fine.
Been browsing the internet for hours, had to ask this question here. Please help!

this is the code that is working fine with my current html:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready(function($){

$('.home_device').animate({marginLeft: '0'}, 600);
  $('.bm-header').addClass('transparent_nav');
  $(window).scroll(function() {    
    var scroll = $(window).scrollTop();
    if (scroll >=150) {
        $(".bm-header").removeClass("transparent_nav");
    } else {
        $(".bm-header").addClass("transparent_nav");
    }
    });

});
</script>
```

Comment: did you add console.log() lines to figure out where it is failing? Does it find elements? Does it enter the mouseenter/mouseleave? does it find the sub menu?

Answer (score 0):

Have you made sure it's running the js properly?  If you place a console.log('mousenter'); inside the mouseenter function what happens?

I'd do the same thing with the mouseleavefunction.
example: `console.log("mouseleave");`
http://codepen.io/dillonlara115/pen/KgQAEq
(make sure your browser dev tools are open to see the console)

If your console adjusts as you hover over these, then you know the js is running.  If its not doing that, then its something else.

Generally speaking you would place your custom js code in the footer so in the case that something is broken in the js, it wouldn't prevent the rest of page from loading properly.  With that being said, you could try placing the custom js in the footer and see if that works.

Answer (score 0):

There was a WordPress plugin causing a conflict, I disabled it and it started to work.

Plugin: Rev Slider one of the oldest versions.